# How to update changes in a custom base Mosaico template?

Tags: mosaico

We've developed our own Mosaico base template for use in CiviCRM. We've made some changes to the base template and updated the template file on our site, however, when trying to use the modified base both new and existing templates aren't updated with our new style tweaks.

Is there a way to flush Mosaico so it re-reads and uses the updated base template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i was building custom templates, clearing browser cache mostly worked. My favorite is to use Ctrl+Shift+R.

And in the UI - I would try creating new template from the base.

An already saved template may not reflect your changes, because saved blocks also store css information and may not use the new one. However any new blocks or deleting a save block and re-creating might work.

Also keep an eye on console for any JS errors before and after your changes. Sometimes even simple css changes break the knockout js, and may not reflect.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've also just tried disabling/enabling the extension which seemed to re-read the template file and update existing templates based on the theme. I'll need to do some more testing

Comment: ... looks like this is a cache issue (last comment was made when I tested on a different machine and I don't think disable/enable does anything)